# mysql displaying options if not selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a query that joins a few tables together and brings me back a set of results. However i have found that this needs to be tweaked to pull back the results in a different way.

Essentially people have a survey which the data is stored into the database.

With the data i need to make a report like in the image below: (this is only a couple of the possible questions for demonstration)

[image]

So the problem i have is for the first question in the image, everyone selected 'yes' which means i have only pulled back that answer. Instead i need to show the possible answer "no" so that i can put 0 on the right(for the amount of people that selected this option).

The query i have is below:

```
            SELECT
                `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
                `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
                `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
                `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
                `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
                `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
                 count(*) as Total,
                `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
            FROM `survey`
            JOIN `surveyQuestions`
                ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`


            JOIN `surveyEntries`
                ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
            JOIN `survey_meta`
                 ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
            JOIN `hw_services`
                ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
            WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
            AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
            AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
            AND `hw_services`.`ID` = 1697
            GROUP BY `surveyQuestions`.`ID`, `survey_meta`.`answer`
```

from this query the result i get is seen below:(only showing 4 rows for demonstration purposes)

[image]

Ok so you can see my problem. The question "Do you live in the city of Birmingham' 25/25 people selected yes. so i get no row for the option of 'No'.

Okay so the table which has all the options is called questionChoices and a picture is seen below as an example:

[image]

I have tried but have had no luck with getting the result i want. And i really do not want to do this through php as it will make extremely messy code.

Does anyone know how i can achieve this? To help you guys i will provide a list of images showing an example from each database table related to this.

**survey:**

[image]

**surveyEntries:**

[image]

**surveyQuestions:**

[image]

**survey_meta:** (to join questions with answers)

[image]

and I have give an example of **questionChoices** earlier in this question

Comment: Why will doing it in PHP produce messy code? I worked on a very similar project and demographic crunching is going to perform much better and be easier to implement using PHP to intersect various arrays of data

Comment: selecting from survey_meta and outer joining to the other tables might help.